# Is it possible to have a component of a screen store information in a context and automatically update a value on the screen that called it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I have an appointments screen in React Native that contains a DateSelect component that I have created.  This component shows as a calendar icon and updates a DateContext with the selected date.

I want to be able to update the value of a useState constant in my appointments screen with the value from the Context once the new date has been selected but I cannot seem to figure it out.

The ContextProvider:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { getFormattedDate } from "../utility/date";

export const DateContext = createContext({
    date: getFormattedDate(new Date()),
    setDate: (date) => {},
});

function DateContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [theDate, setTheDate] = useState("");

    function setDate(date) {
        setTheDate(date);
    }

    const value = {
        date: theDate,
        setDate: setDate,
    };

    return <DateContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</DateContext.Provider>;
}

export default DateContextProvider;
```

The DateSelect component:

```js
import { StyleSheet, View, Pressable } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { DateContext } from "../store/dateContext";
import { getFormattedDate } from "../utility/date";

export default function DateSelect({ color, size, update }) {
    const datePickedCtx = useContext(DateContext);
    const [datePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisible] = useState(false);

    function showDatePicker() {
        setDatePickerVisible(true);
    }

    function hideDatePicker() {
        setDatePickerVisible(false);
    }

    function handleConfirm(date) {
        console.log("A date has been picked", date);
        datePickedCtx.setDate(getFormattedDate(date));
        hideDatePicker();
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Pressable onPress={showDatePicker}>
                <Ionicons name="calendar" color={color} size={size} />
            </Pressable>
            <DateTimePickerModal
                isVisible={datePickerVisible}
                mode="date"
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onCancel={hideDatePicker}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

And the Appointments screen I want to update:

```js
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import DateSelect from "../UI/DateSelect";
import { GlobalStyles } from "../constants/GlobalStyles";
import { DateContext } from "../store/dateContext";

export default function Appointments() {
    const datePickedCtx = useContext(DateContext);
    
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(datePickedCtx.date);

    // I need to somehow update setSelectedDate when datePickedCtx is updated

    console.log("DateContextOutput", datePickedCtx);

    return (
        <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
            <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.dateText}>{selectedDate}</Text>
                <DateSelect size={24} color={GlobalStyles.colors.lightText} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get("screen").width;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    rootContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 8,
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    dateContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.primary500,
        width: deviceWidth < 380 ? 200 : 200,
        padding: 8,
        marginVertical: 8,
        borderRadius: 8,
    },
    dateText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: GlobalStyles.colors.lightText,
    },
});
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to approach this problem.

Comment: Since you are just displaying selectedDate inside the Appointments, how about just displaying the datePickedCtx directly?

Comment: Otherwise, you can use the useEffect hook to set the State and set the datePickedCtx as a dependency.

Comment: Would: <Text style={styles.dateText}>{datePickedCtx.date}</Text>
work for you?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis what you have suggested works on the initial page load, however it fails to update when a new date is picked

Comment: Which of the 2 methods are you using? @Spacejocks
On a simple React version of this setup, it seems to be updating: https://codesandbox.io/s/72693776-jjue1k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I added the useEffect function you provided and it still wouldn't update.  I've since merged the screen and component and its working for now.  Ideally I'd have liked it to be its own thing to keep my code tidier.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the Context value directly or use the `useEffect` hook for that:

```
export default function Appointments() {
    const datePickedCtx = useContext(DateContext);
    
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(datePickedCtx.date);
    useEffect(()=>{
      setSelectedDate(datePickedCtx.date);
    }, [datePickedCtx]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
            <View style={styles.dateContainer}>

                <Text style={styles.dateText}>Via State: {selectedDate}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.dateText}>Via Context: {datePickedCtx.date}</Text>

                <DateSelect size={24} color={GlobalStyles.colors.lightText} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```